# Can't copy/paste to/from system clipboard in Terminal on Mac

Tags: terminal, clipboard, copy-paste, terminal.app

I can't copy or paste to or from the system clipboard within the Terminal.  Neither `Cmd-C`/`Cmd-V` nor menus work.  Instead, Terminal seems to be using it's own buffer for copy/paste operations.  I am able to access the system clipboard only using `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same problem occur when you create a new user account (i.e. default settings) and try to do it there? What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: Yep...problem persists. Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: Unfortunately, after not receiving any responses to my question for months, and it now being several computers later, I no longer have the problem or am able to test any suggested solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Try the right click menu. I know that I can paste with right click but never tried to copy sth. Like you said, shortcuts don't work unfortunately

Comment: Shortcuts *should* work out of the box. It would be very weird otherwise.

Comment: Yes...on every other Mac I own and use, shortcuts should and do work.  On this Mac, none of the Edit menu, context menu, or shortcuts work.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your Terminal's character set to *UTF8* from `Preferences -> Advanced`. My paste didn't work earlier when I had the character set as *ISO Latin 1* - after changing it to *UTF-8*, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue. But above answers didn't quite help me.

Issue was the a process called `pboard`. This is the clipboard service for terminals.

- Open the `Activity Monitor`.
- Search the `pboad` process and just terminate it.
- A new instance of `pboard` should automatically start
- After this, the copy-paste should work as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting what u copy and  then to copy press Ctrl+Shift+c and to paste press Ctrl+Shift+V

Comment: This is a useful answer because it is  not obvious to use `CTL-Shift-V` instead of simply `CMD-V`

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer. Worked for me when I had this issue just now. I'm running macOS 10.13.4.